# Varnish hasn't been configured correctly and is causing the websites you mentioned to load to a "defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: varnish

after installing varnish all domains on my server using HTTP redirect to -http://my_domain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi.
I went to cPanel Technical Support and they reply to me with this answer.. basically, Varnish isn't configured properly.

> We have been able to test your server's configuration and found that Varnish hasn't been configured correctly and is causing the websites you mentioned to load to a "defaultwebpage.cgi". We have been able to confirm that Apache is loading correctly and upon testing, we can see that it's listening on Port 8080:

> [19:41:57 server1 root@94376622 /home/prowp/public_html/my_domain.com]cPs# netstat -l -n -p | grep httpd
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11666/httpd
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11666/httpd
> unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     101366516 11667/httpd          /etc/apache2/run/cgid_sock.21361

> if you request the websites on the apache http port locally on the server, we can see that it's loading correctly

> [19:42:53 server1 root@94376622 /home/prowp/public_html/my_domain.com]cPs# curl -I http://my_domain.com:8080
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
> Date: Sun, 24 Oct 2021 16:43:29 GMT
> Server: Apache
> X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.24
> X-Redirect-By: WordPress
> Upgrade: h2,h2c
> Connection: Upgrade
> Location: https://www.my_domain.com/
> Vary: Accept-Encoding
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> But upon testing it without directing it to Apache for it to use Varnish it then loads the "defaultwebpage.cgi":

> [19:43:48 server1 root@94376622 /home/prowp/public_html/my_domain.com]cPs# curl http://my_domain.com

> [19:46:48 server1 root@94376622 /home/prowp/public_html/my_domain.com]cPs# curl http://my_domain.com

[19:56:33 server1 root@94376622 /home/prowp/public_html/my_domain.com]cPs#

Maybe someone can help?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after digging to solve the issue I across this article [Configure Varnish and your web server](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-configure.html)

the advice in section 5:

> If Varnish and Apache are running on the same host, we recommend you use an IP address or hostname and not localhost.
> but in my /etc/varnish/default.vcl i added wrong ip address...

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "80";
```

}

so i change it to my ip address

```
backend default {
.host = "my_ip_address";
.port = "80";
```

}

as varnish and apache are on the same host.
and now no more cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi. file in front of my domain when using HTTP.